# What's the difference between .xcdatamodeld and BadgerNew.xcdatamodel

Tags: xcode, core-data

I think xcode 3 use the latter and xcode 4 use the former.

Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.xcdatamodeld is a container for .xcdatamodel files.  It's used for versioning and migration.  When moving from v1 of the model to v2, you add a new xcdatamodel to it that has v2 along with the mapping model.

Comment: I already have an xcdatamodel file from the old projects how should I incorporate that?

Comment: So xcdatamodeld is a container. How do I add an old xcdatamodel to the xcdatamodeld file? I select add files to xcdatamodeld and it doesn't work out. the xcdatamodel is simply added to the project not to xcdatamodeld.